# List of StackOverflow questions to migrate

Tags: discussion, scope, questions, migration

Ivo Wetzel has listed in detail a great set of [prerequisites for migrating SO questions](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50/are-reviews-of-code-in-stack-overflow-answers-in-scope/71#71) over here. Migration is a win-win situation, so we should invest some energy in bringing good on-topic questions to Code Review.

While there are a lot of candidates waiting to be discovered, some have already been tagged for us:

- [**code-review**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code-review)
- [**peer-review**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/peer-review)
- [code-review-standards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code-review-standards)
- [review](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/review)
- [readability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/readability)
- [refactor-my-code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/refactor-my-code)
- [pair-programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pair-programming)
- [guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/guidelines)
- [review-board](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/review-board)
- [software-quality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/software-quality)
- [conventions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/conventions)
- [coding-standards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/coding-standards) (?)
- [naming-conventions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/naming-conventions) (?)
- [coding-style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/coding-style)  (?)
- [variable-naming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/variable-naming) (?)
- [style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/style)
- [refactoring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/refactoring)
- [feedback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/feedback)

Taking a look at [code-reviews](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-reviews) at Programmers would also be interesting. I think it'd be better if we only add to discussions there and avoid trying to migrate questions.

I suggest that we use this question to list candidates for migration, and maybe review all questions tagged review as a first step. If we can find questions on-topic for this site that have been closed, even better.

If you want to add or remove tags from the list above, say it in comments. Any new questions you can open to discuss scope based on this discussion would help us work things out.

Feel free to answer with single questions or lists, this is all going to be a wiki anyway.

Answer (score 2):

I had a couple of questions related to the subject:

- [Is this (Lock-Free) Queue Implementation Thread-Safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634368/is-this-lock-free-queue-implementation-thread-safe)

  - I have recreated it [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/224/is-this-lock-free-queue-implementation-thread-safe).
- [Could you please review my Quick Int Parser implementation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419952/could-you-please-review-my-quick-int-parser-implementation)

Answer (score 1):

**[code-review](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code-review)**

- [(3 tierish) Database access pattern code review](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4731523/555569)
- [Java Code Review: Merge sorted lists into a single sorted list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1774256/java-code-review-merge-sorted-lists-into-a-single-sorted-list)
- [I'm trying to make a loosely coupled architecture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4501157/im-trying-to-make-a-loosely-coupled-architecture)
- [The last piece of the puzzle: Is this code NOW decoupled correctly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4462303/the-last-piece-of-the-puzzle-is-this-code-now-decoupled-correctly)
- [Code review for a dynamic jQuery loader with version checking and jQuery object isolation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4425851/code-review-for-a-dynamic-jquery-loader-with-version-checking-and-jquery-object-i)
- [What do you think about the quality of this php code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4173203/what-do-you-think-about-the-quality-of-this-php-code)
- [Optimization in Common Decalaration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4569905/optimization-in-common-decalaration)

[**feedback**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/feedback)

- [Feedback, question about my module and if i should change anything ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3868401/feedback-question-about-my-module-and-if-i-should-change-anything)

[**readability**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/readability)

- [naming of physical quantities in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4227503/naming-of-physical-quantities-in-python)

[**refactoring**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/refactoring)

- [How to refactor this Objective-C code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4238960/how-to-refactor-this-objective-c-code)