# How can we promote our site?

Tags: discussion, beta-progress, publicity, top-7

One of the [7 essential meta questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/the-7-essential-meta-questions-of-every-beta/):

> This is rapidly becoming a hot issue across the entire network: how
>   to promote your site and how to reach
>   out to the experts and pundits in your
>   industry. We can come up with budgets
>   and promotions but — more than any
>   other issue raised here — the means
>   and ideas about how to reach your
>   target audience HAS TO come from you
>   and your community. Has to. Has to,
>   has to, has to! We simply are not
>   experts in your field. We don’t have
>   the the connections nor the experience
>   you bring to the table. You are both
>   our evangelist and our ambassador.

A good way to start is to search for questions tagged [promotion] on other metas.

Also, read [A Recipe to Promote your Site](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/a-recipe-to-promote-your-site/).

Comment: `if you've ever wanted to ask "does this code make my ass look fat?" now you can: http://codereview.stackexchange.com` posted at http://twitter.com/#!/codinghorror/status/30386685497843713

Comment: the answer is obviously an unequivocal yes it does.

Answer (score 5):

I think what makes sense for *this* site is to invite your peers to review your code.

> I just posted some code I'm not sure about -- I respect you guys' and gals' opinions, can you take a look at it and give me feedback?

Remember that **we do NOT require logins of ANY KIND to participate here, so even if they just "type feedback in input box, enter name, press [submit]" it will work.**

In other words, there is no login barrier.

Answer (score 3):

A good start would be to ping the mailing lists for code review tools, maybe for test frameworks and related issues. Mentioning Code Review on [these questions](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87/list-of-stackoverflow-questions-to-migrate) and suitable ones in Programmers would help too.

Comment: +1 - Was going to link to that. I'll be keeping my eye out for questions on SO that are better suited for Code Review.

Answer (score 2):

Does your social network (Farcebook, LinkedIn etc) include other coders?  Say something to them.