# On migrating from SO: how to do this efficiently and appropriately.

Tags: discussion, migration

Not having the privileges on SO to manually migrate questions, I thought I'd flag [the question I was looking to migrate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5569863/how-to-make-this-tlv-reader-class-look-nicer-and-work-smoother) as 'Off Topic' so that I *may* be able to select CR as the recommended place.

I'd [previously noticed that this list is not flexible](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84104/off-topic-but-no-appropriate-stack-exchange-on-list) and now come to the conclusion it is predefined, inasmuch that the available sites will always be the same (?), meaning no chance of the site you might suggest popping up if it isn't there already.

Now, this dialog isn't the subject of my question, but gives context to what I'm trying to achieve. Given [this question](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87/list-of-stackoverflow-questions-to-migrate), my objective was simply to aid in migrating questions from SO in the most appropriate and discreet fashion.

My question now breaks into two parts:

- How should this be done?

  - I say discreetly as I know SE mods already have a lot to wade through, this means flagging to 'close' as 'off-topic' requires them the *think* about where it ought to be, while I wouldn't really have suggested it if it wasn't quite obvious this still requires them to either second-guess me or ponder it individually.
  - Any other mechanism is just as laborious for someone, somewhere - and just degrades in appropriateness.
  - Just leave it: undesirable, though I'm not fanatical about migrating the question that urged this one, I don't want to have, or seem to have an attitude of ignorance or laziness towards this practice on the whole.
- When should this be done?

  - [This is detailed to some degree](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50/are-reviews-of-code-in-stack-overflow-answers-in-scope/71#71) but I'm wondering if age and responses (by members other than the OP) should be considered?
  - Also, should the state of the thread be considered (i.e. accepted answer present)?

The first point of my first question seems the only way to go right now for that matter, but obviously just here looking for input.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the past I flagged such questions for moderator attention with a comment stating the site I thought it should be migrated to.

The going recommendation seems to be that if a question is off topic and you do not have the rights to take direct action (vote to close-migrate) then you should flag it.

Of-course, if the question is of a low quality then it's probably better to have it closed rather than migrated.

Comment: Also, I think its ok to migrate relatively new questions that already have an accepted answer, but if its an old question then just leave it where it lay.

Answer (score 4):

I would certainly prioritize SO questions where *there is no error or problem to be solved* yet the poster has provided code with the intent of some kind of subjective critique.

That's a textbook example of a code review question and it really doesn't fit on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score -3):

**WHOA!** This site is still in beta. I don't think *any* questions should be migrated until the beta period is complete.